# How to send an excel file with a macro by email

Tags: excel, email-attachments, vba

I recieved an excel workbook with data and I added a macro to it with a button that activates the macro. I have to return the excel workbook with the macro by email. I added the workbook to the email as an attachment. I wanted to check the attached file to see if everything is ok and I saw that the macro isn't there.

The excel file is macro enabled.

How should this be done? Thank you.

Comment: if you are recording macro in the workbook you have received means add this bit of code to macro, this will send the mail of active workbook, `ActiveWorkbook.SendMail Recipients:="abc@xyz.com"`

Comment: @expfresh I'm not sending the email by the macro I just want the macro to be included with the file when I send and that seems to be working sometimes and sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

Save it as .XLSM before sending, it is working with small test. you can specify the workbook name also if more than one workbook is open.

```
Sub marco()
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Range("a21").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=sum(a2:a20)"
End With
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
    "C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\file.xlsm", FileFormat:=52
    ActiveWorkbook.SendMail Recipients:="abc@xyz.com"

End Sub
```